# In a CV - I taught vs I was teaching vs I had been teaching

Tags: past-tense

If I need to make a point in my CV to describe myself (after I quited my job as a teacher) what should I say (and I am trying to stress my role or qualification here) ?

1. > I was teaching my students academic oral language in the context of various content areas.
2. > I had been teaching my students academic oral language in the context of various content areas.
3. > I taught my students academic oral language in the context of various content areas.

I think 1 and 3 is ok but I am not sure of 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the context of your CV, you are explaining things that you did.  Simple past (your third example) is best, because you are not attempting to place your statement in a time context with another statement.  Look at these:

> I was teaching my students when the fire alarm rang and we had to leave the building.
>   I had been teaching for five years by the time I turned 25.
>   I taught academic oral language for five years.

In the first example, teaching is an activity that was ongoing when another event occurred.  In the second example, teaching is an activity that occurred for a specific time period in the past that ended before another event occurred.  (These two are somewhat interchangeable.  For a good explanation of the difference, see [here](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastcontinuous.html) and [here](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastperfectcontinuous.html).)

In the last example, teaching is an activity that occurred during some five-year period in the past.  This is most likely what you want.  If you wanted to use one of the other tenses, you'd need to compare teaching to other past events, and those events wouldn't be relevant in your CV.

Now, one other possibility is the present perfect:

> I have taught academic oral language.

This is fairly common if you are describing past experience that you have now: I have taught academic oral language, I have sold vacuum cleaners, etc.  If you are describing the present state of your past experience, this is typically the tense used.

Comment: Thank you Bob for your detailed clear answer but still a question if you could help , if I want to say that I "taught" academic oral language and that gave me a good experience and skills, Have I to still use "taught" ? Because teaching here is not an activity that was ongoing when another event occurred , as I think ...

Comment: A thoughtful question.  Yes, you would still just use the simple past.  The other versions we've discussed are used to position the event described in a time context with another event.  You're not doing that; you're describing two different actions in the past that are related but not in any specific time context.  You're not saying *when* the teaching gave you the experience.  Compare "By the time I had been teaching for five years, I felt that I had gained good experience."

Comment: thank you very much , now it is much more clear. But concerning your last example "I have taught academic oral languages" as far as  I know I can not use it because I am no longer teach academic oral language.  You make a new point for me ( as I get it) is that you says that the sentence can also denote or speak about the teaching experience. Is that what do you mean ? Sorry if I have many questions for you.

Comment: No, you can do this.  I have taught piano, personally, and I don't do it now.  If I were doing it now, I would say that I am teaching piano, or that I teach piano, or that I have been teaching piano.  When I say that I have taught piano, I'm saying that I taught piano at some time before now, and that I may or may not still be doing it.  (If I were to say that I have taught piano for ten years, the implication is that I started ten years ago and I'm still teaching.)  If you are discussing those past experiences that make you the person that you are now, you can use the present perfect. ...

Comment: ... For example, I *have developed* about 25 software applications in my career (which may or may not be over), but I *developed* an application to track goods as they were transported along railroads.

Comment: It seems present perfect denotes implications of actions happened in the past (good for CVs for example) and past simple for describing  past actions as facts, Thank you Bob so much, it is so clear now.

Comment: Yes, you're getting the hang of it.  However, I think the use of simple past would be preferable in CV's.  Perhaps in more informal discussion in an interview, you might use past perfect more.  In my CV, I might say that I taught piano.  Then, in an interview, someone might ask me if I know anything about electronic music.  I might say "I've studied it."  Then, I might explain further: "When I was a student at IU, I took a year-long electronic music class."  Does that make sense?

Comment: Interesting points here,  but Why it is preferable in CVs to use past simple ? , is that because you just give facts or points ? But what about if you want to make impression in your CV that you taught piano and you have (now) much expreince and skills ?

Comment: In my opinion, the CV is the place to state your skills and experience, not sell them.  If your skills match the job requirements, you'll get an interview.  The interview is where you sell the skills, by proving that you have what you say you have.  If you could sell your skills in a CV, nobody would go to the trouble of having interviews.  If you taught piano for five years, you have experience.  If they want to find out whether you have skill as well, they'll have to have you in and hear you play and watch you teach.

Comment: "If you taught piano for five years, you have experience." .....

So do  you mean Past simple has its own  implications but it stress the"facts" themselves (more than the implications) but the Present perfect stress the implications more than the facts?

Comment: I wouldn't say that is necessarily true.  Simple past simply refers to a past event; present perfect refers to a past event and relates it to the present.  Sometimes it doesn't make much difference which you use.  Typical CV style uses simple past, probably for no better reason than that it is more concise.  Take a look at those links I posted, if you haven't already.

Answer (score -2):

2 is not correct only because you said you already quit your job. That means you are not teaching any more.

"I had been teaching" implies that you are still teaching but you are not. Makes sense?

Comment: I disagree that "I had been teaching" implies that you still are teaching.  It means that you taught up to a specific point in time in the past.  "I have been teaching" implies that you still are teaching.